# Extracting specific data from a webpage-source programmatically

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, xml

**The following question applies to any programming language**

I am working on a program which on providing the webpage-source-code as input will extract some specific kind of data.

Suppose I provided the following page-source as input to my program:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="a" class="product-name">Product A</td>
        <td id="1" class="product-price">$100</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="b" class="product-name">Product B</td>
        <td id="2" class="product-price">$200</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="c" class="product-name">Product C</td>
        <td id="3" class="product-price">$300</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

On this webpage, there are products mentioned along with their selling price. The webpage look like this:

```
 Product A: $100
 Product B: $200
 Product C: $300
```

I want to use this page-source to copy this data to database. Since the product names and their prices are mentioned in fix tags and classes (like `<td>` or `<div>` etc), How can I extract the data these programmatically? Is there any good algorithm/code/library to extract such data from a page-source?

I think this can be done by using `getElementByID` in Javascript. But I am not sure. Or XML can be used? How? Any other good method/algorithms?

**Note**: I am doing this to my own website. I already have an old website and I want to use all the data in my new one. Entering all the data manually again is a huge task. So I want to copy data from my old one. Any programming language is okay with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

By the way, it's called **crawling**.

Answer (score 2):

To query data from XML documents you can make use of the [`xpath` language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) that is available in many programming languages. It explicitly deals with XML documents, not strings.

Another approach is to do a string analysis of the documents you want to extract data from and extract the data as needed on a much lower level. This can sometimes be faster, but XPATH is much more robust as it can differ between tags, attributes and values.

Normally you just need a transformation from the documents into another form, for this many languages provide an interface to [`XSLT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) and [`XQuery`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

A term you can search for is **[scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)**, if you're looking for some resources for PHP, checkout [web-scraping-with-php](https://github.com/elazar/web-scraping-with-php) which is [available in print as well](http://matthewturland.com/2010/04/20/web-scraping-with-php-now-available/).